# Why are Pokemon in my Photodex marked with a crown?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

Some of the Pokemon in my Photodex are marked with a small sparkling crown icon. What does this crown icon mean?

[image: Photodex with crowns]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Pokemon is marked with a crown after getting a photo for each of the 4 star ratings. The crown is visible on both the individual Pokemon page and on the list of Pokemon.

Note: The "updated" icon (!) will take priority over the crown on the Pokemon list.

[image: Bidoof with all photos]